# Using svg.js from the command line to create SVG files

Tags: svg.js

I want to use svg.js in a command-line utility to generate raw SVG files. But from what I can tell from the documentation, I can only add SVG content to an element in an HTML file. Is there a way to instead generate SVG files directly or to generate a raw string that I could then write to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

svg.js needs a dom of some form to create svg elements. You dont neccarily need a html dom. For server use you might want to take a look into svgdom: https://github.com/svgdotjs/svgdom

svgdom is a non-standard dom which means it has enough to run svg.js but not more and not standard conform in any case. However, it is near enough to the "truth" that you can use it for lots of stuff. It enables svg.js to run on node.
Even stuff like getBBox and getBoundingClientRect works.

Comment: How did I miss that repo?! Thanks! That's exactly what I need.